# how to get the server display name and process name in Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere-liberty

In the WebSphere (node) application server, there are the following classes that provide the display name and the process name,
what is the equivalent in WebSphere Liberty Profile

Classes from the WebSphere (traditional) are

- com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminServiceFactory
- com.ibm.websphere.runtime.ServerName

I am using Liberty Profile v 8.5.5.8

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve server info from the ServerInfoMBean in Liberty as described in [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic.](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.kernel.service_1.0-javadoc/index.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-17-1-1-11&lang=en)  For more info on how to use management mbeans on Liberty, see [this topic](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_mbeans.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-1-15-2&lang=en).